# Azure VMSS instance "Latest model" meaning

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I look into my VMSS in Azure, and enters the "instances" blade, for each instance there is a property "Latest model" which can be either "No" or "Yes".

[image: The property looks like this.]

What does this property mean? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 9):

The `Latest Model` inside the VMSS instances blade is know as the ***[Latest Scaleset Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#the-scale-set-model)***.

If it is `Yes`, then its the latest scaleset model and vice versa for `No`. There are couple of ways to change it to Yes i.e. `Manual` , `Automatic` and `Rolling` which can be set from the ***upgrade policy blade of the VMSS*** .

[image]

***In `Manual` you will have to run the below command to update the scaleset model:***

***[Azure CLI :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vmss-update-instances)***

```
az vmss update-instances --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --instance-ids {instanceIds}
```

**Output :**

***Before Update:***

[image]

***Only Update the last one with `instance ID = 8` :***

[image]

[image]

***Update the remaining two by giving space separated instance id's:***

[image]

[image]

For More details on ***Modify Scaleset Model*** you can refer this ***[`Microsoft Documentaion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#how-to-bring-vms-up-to-date-with-the-latest-scale-set-model)***.

Answer (score 0):

Once the scale set model is updated, the new configuration applies to any new VMs created in the scale set. However, the models for the existing VMs in the scale set must still be brought up-to-date with the latest overall scale set model. In the model for each VM is a boolean property called latestModelApplied that indicates whether or not the VM is up-to-date with the latest overall scale set model (true means the VM is up-to-date with the latest model).

Refer to the document here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#how-to-update-global-scale-set-properties